# Add together two UIAccelerationValue's?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, addition

I am not sure if this is a stupid question or not so please bear with me here. Anyway I have two `UIAccelerationValue's`. When I individually `NSLog` their results I get values like this respectively:

```
1. Value: -0.016186

2. Value2: -0.033460
```

However when I add or subtract the two `UIAccelerationValue's` together, I get values like this:

```
Value: -571.142049
Value: -1085.174017
Value: -2061.834754
Value: -3917.490156
Value: -7443.235420
Value: -14142.151420
```

As you can see the values just keep increasing exponentially.

Anyway, how can I just simply add or subtract the two `UIAccelerationValues` together without the results I am getting now?

Comment: UIAccelerationValue is just a double ... `typedef double UIAccelerationValue;` Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you're able to post a bit of the code in question. As people have mentioned, UIAccelerationValue is a double. Are you adding the UIAcceration.X|Y|Z from successive readings or are you just reading the UIAcceleration and adding or subtracting two of the axes together? The first makes sense since as the docs mention the sensor is noisy and best readings are obtained by using an average or running average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are storing the result of the addition/subtraction and are adding/subtracting over and over again, hence the increased, large values

UIAccelerationValue is just a double (see UIAccelerometer.h):

```
typedef double UIAccelerationValue;
```

With the following example you get expected output:

```
UIAccelerationValue xOne = -0.016186;
UIAccelerationValue xTwo = -0.033460;

NSLog(@"%f", xOne + xTwo); // prints out -0.049646
NSLog(@"%f", xOne - xTwo); // prints out 0.017274
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%f", xOne **-** xTwo); // prints out 0.017274

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in UIAcceleration but here is an example from a sample code. Hope it helps.

```
#define kAccelerometerFrequency        50.0 //Hz
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1


UIAccelerationValue gravX;
UIAccelerationValue gravY;
UIAccelerationValue gravZ;
gravX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (gravX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
gravY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (gravY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
gravZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (gravZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

UIAccelerationValue accelX = acceleration.x - ( (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (gravX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );

UIAccelerationValue accelY = acceleration.y - ( (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (gravY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
UIAccelerationValue accelZ = acceleration.z - ( (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (gravZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
accelX *= 9.81f;
accelY *= 9.81f;
accelZ *= 9.81f;
accelX = [self tendToZero:accelX];
accelY = [self tendToZero:accelY];
accelZ = [self tendToZero:accelZ];

UIAccelerationValue vector = sqrt(pow(accelX,2)+pow(accelY,2)+pow(accelZ, 2));
UIAccelerationValue acce = vector - prevVelocity;
UIAccelerationValue velocity = (((acce - prevAcce)/2) * (1/kAccelerometerFrequency)) + prevVelocity;

NSLog(@"X %g Y %g Z %g, Vector %g, Velocity %g",accelX,accelY,accelZ,vector,velocity);
```